# angular-file-upload breaks IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I`m trying to upload a file via [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) and on IE9 it falls back to legacy upload via flash.

The steps to reproduce this are:

1. Press the file input to upload file
2. Select file and press open
3. IE9 completely breaks with an error of "Internet Explorer has stopped working" and it restarts.

The way I am uploading the file is via a $watch on the file input so basically the upload should start automatically after selecting the file.

Has anyone encountered this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any library for that? More info would be nice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is reporting an issue on a library - it should be on github.

Comment: @Meznaric - the link was on the text itself but I'll leave it here as well - https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Comment: @EdHinchliffe their example of the library doesn't break it so I doubt the error is in the library as is in the way that I am using it.

Comment: So show us how you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

It's breaking in IE9 because IE9 does not support canvas. IF you view this URL in IE9 [angular-file-upload](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/) you will see they have the es5-shim library:

```
<!-- Fix for old browsers -->
    <script src="http://nervgh.github.io/js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://nervgh.github.io/js/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../console-sham.js"></script>
```